# how to use Offline googleMap in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

how to use Offline googleMap in my app

what I'm wont is to download map of any country then let my application use it
but in offline mode

is there any way to use googleMap offline inside my application ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use downloaded maps with `GoogleMaps`. But there is `OpenSteetMaps` which could use downloaded maps. Library for android: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Comment: it's not easy to use :(
but it's the solution

Comment: Pretty sure there is no intent to update osmdroid for Google Maps API v2. Check out Mapbox's Android SDK.